# Axon Kafka ext - EventPublicationFailedException if command service is horizontally scaled

Tags: apache-kafka, axon

## Setup

- Standalone Kafka instance
- MySQL database as event store
- Command service implemented using SpringBoot and AxonFrameowrk Kafka Extension
- Command Service is deployed on K8S cluster

## Test Scenario

#### Jemeter script with 500 concurrent test users firing command over REST

- Command Service with single instance - **All Successfull**
- Command Service scaled to 2 instances - **All Successfull**
- Command Service scaled to 3 or 4 instances - **Errros observed for certain requests with exception as below**

`ERROR[0;39m o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.axonframework.messaging.EventPublicationFailedException: Event publication failed: Exception occurred while committing kafka transaction]`

Checked the kafka extenstion source and could see this exception is mapped to `ProducerFencedException`

Seems its generating duplicate event / transaction ids when command services are horizontally scaled.

Please suggest remidy or alternative to avoid these exceptions.

Comment: You are talking about a command service which is connected with the kafka extension, but that breaks with the conception that the Axon Kafka Extension is intended to handle events. Commands and Events have very distinct routing paradigms, and the Kafka extension is tailored towards event routing. So, are you using the extension to pass commands over it?

Comment: Added, as you stated, the exception originates from Axon's `KafkaPublisher` and occurs because the Kafka `Producer` cannot start a transaction. Why/how this occurs is no so much an Axon issue, but more a thing to search within Kafka's implementation or your own Kafka configuration.